# How to Format USB Stick to a Low Level Format Fat16 Fat32 File System to Record Rescue Disk for Antivirus Software

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, formatting, fat32, fat16

I would like to know how or which app/software can I use to format a USB stick to FAT 16 or FAT 32 low level format thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-format thumb drive](https://superuser.com/questions/396637/re-format-thumb-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "low-level format" should be avoided because many people misuse this term - it only applies to floppy disks and very old types of hard drives.  It's just "format."

When you plug in the USB drive, the drive should show up in "This PC" in File Explorer.  To get to File Explorer, press the Windows key + E and it will pop up.  You will have to look in the left to find "This PC"

Find your drive, then right click it.  "Format" should be among the options presented.  Make sure you select "FAT32" or "FAT" and *not* "NTFS" or "exFAT."

If you do not see FAT32 or FAT, your USB drive is probably bigger than 32GB.  You should use a smaller drive because you'll probably be wasting a lot of space on it to simply record some antivirus utilities.